# Selenium nth match by id without common parent

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I have to test some complicated web service using Selenium.

Problem is that `id`s of elements are changing from session to session.
For example there is bunch of *inputs* each have `id` with prefix `textf_id_DComboBox_` and ends with a consecutive numbers, starting number is random (session dependent).
Those *inputs* doesn't have a common parent so `nth-child` doesn't work.\

I can find first *input* by using selector: `css=input[id^='textf_id_DComboBox_']` but I have no idea how to find next items (1-7) which match this selector.
I've found some suggestions on stackoverflow that `xpath` selector should be used, but I was unable to adopt examples for my use case.

*Update*:
I have also alternative selector which captures first input: `css=td.DForm_treeGridNoWrap input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this XPath in order to select all inputs that contain a common id:

```
string comboBoxXPath = "//input[contains(@id, 'textf_id_DComboBox')]";
List<WebElement> comboBoxElements = driver.findElements(By.XPath(comboBoxXPath));
```

At this point, you can iterate through the entire collection, or you can select which one you'd like to interact with by using an index:

```
comboBoxElements[1]
comboBoxElements[2]
comboBoxElements[3]

etc...
```

Comment: I'm using selenium scripts, so your answer has lead me to proper solution: `xpath=(//input[contains(@id, 'textf_id_DComboBox_')])[7]`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, that descrption does not help that much. You can try these tricks:

- You can call `findElement` on `WebElement` This trick will probably not work, because those IDs do not have common parent. But if they are wrapped, say, in table, you can find the table first:

  ```
   WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("the-table"));
  ```

And then to find all input in such table:

```
      List<WebElement> inputs = table.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
```

- Install Selenium IDE to your firefox and try record testcase by using it. You can play with target in Selenium IDE.
- Dirty approach

  ```
     List<WebElement> allInputs = driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
  ```

  Will find **all** inputs in such page.

Footnote: The code is Java and `driver` variable is considered as healthy instance of `WebDriver`